# Error in inflating adding new elements in arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to actually implement a listview with different layout in each row. and I am stuck with this. i get an error in `rows.add(new ImageRow(LayoutInflater.from(FeedAdapter.this), feed));` same with the `descriptionRow` part.

```
final List<Row> rows;
FeedAdapter(List<Feed> feeds) {
    rows = new ArrayList<Row>();//member variable

    for (Feed feed : feeds) {
        //if it has an image, use an ImageRow
        if (feed.getImageID() != null) {
           rows.add(new ImageRow(LayoutInflater.from(FeedAdapter.this), feed));
        } else {//otherwise use a DescriptionRow
            rows.add(new DescriptionRow(LayoutInflater.from(FeedAdapter.this), feed));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method from(Context) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (FeedAdapter)

Comment: that is the error eclipse gives me.

Comment: `LayoutInflater.from(contextReference)` expects a `Context` reference(like an activity for example). You are using `FeedAdapter.this` which from the looks of it it isn't a valid `Context`. Pass a reference to the activity where you use the `FeedAdapter`.

Comment: @Luksprog post that as an answer and not a comment.

Answer (score -1):

`rows` is `final`. I am not sure you can keep adding to it after it has a value. `final` means once you set the value, you don't want to change it. Try it without `final`.

Comment: tried it without final. still didn't work. I'm actually basing it on this tutorial. http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/ I tried to run the code from the tutorial it works just fine. I think there are still imports, or things missing.  :(

Comment: Actually eclipse gives me this error: The method from(Context) in the type LayoutInflater is not applicable for the arguments (FeedAdapter)

Comment: This is incorrect.  `final` just means that you can't assign another `List` to the `rows` field.  You can mutate the object as much as you want.